# Many-to-many withouth relations (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have **two application**, in two different server. 
In the first Laravel application I have my **User model**, and in the secound application I have my **Blog model**.

There is a **many-to-many relationship** between them, a user can have multiple blogs, and one blog can belongs to many user.
They have two different database, but everything is **built like its only one app** in one server.

They have a REST API, and its communicating between them. The problem is, I cant set up real relations between them (like **belongsToMany** in the Eloquent Model), and I can't list User's blogs.

Is there a way to copy the **"User::blogs()"** relation function, with some query work on **Blog:: class**? For e.g. select all blogs where user_id is equal to 1 in the pivot table?

Comment: Why can't you set up relationships?

Comment: Because its on another server, in another laravel application.
They can't see each other, I have only API comminication between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class User extends Model{
  protected $connection = 'Your Connection';

  public function blogs(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Blog::class);
  }

}
```

Blog.php

```
class Blog extends Model{

  protected $connection = 'Your other connection';

public function users(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }

}
```

You can set the multiple connections in your `database.php` and assign each model a different connection.

I am assuming that you have a user_blogs  table. some where

hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I know this, but as I said, I have two different laravel application. But here is the solution:

**Blog::join('blog_user', 'blogs.id','=','blog_user.blog_id')->where('blog_user.user_id', '=', $this->userId)->get();**

Comment: `  protected $connection = 'Your other connection';
` this is for different connection

Answer (score 0):

I found it, like this:

```
Blog::join('blog_user', 'blogs.id','=','blog_user.blog_id')->where('blog_user.user_id', '=', $this->userId)->get();
```